# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) due to entrance value in python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am trying to call the function add_site. But each time, I tried the Python console shows:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

My code is shown below. Each print function is verified with success. Instance and solution are dictionaries and the others are array or list.

[call to the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMkpl.png)

[definition of the function add_site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XEdd.png)

How to solve this problem ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please include the code as text, not as an image.

Comment: add the code as text not images

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason is that you are returning only one variable instead of two in the first if condition when it is set to True.

Also, you should add your code as text instead of images so it's easier for us to have a look.